# Android studio LoggedErrorException after update to 0.9.9

Tags: gradle, android-studio, updating

I am having this error output since I updated Android Studio to actual version (0.9.9) from 0.8v...
I have Windows 8 and I tried to change:

classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0-rc2'

to:

classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'

I did this change in my main build.gradle file and in build.gradle of facebook and pulltorefresh libraries in my project.

Also, in main build.gradle I changed:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
       runProguard false
       proguardFile getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')
       signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
}
```

to:

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFile getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
```

Obviusly, the project worked pefectly before update studio.

[error (pastebin)](http://pastebin.com/gzGwA5p6)

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
}
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
compileSdkVersion 19
buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 19
}

signingConfigs {

    release {
        storeFile file('C:\\Trabajo\\Miguel\\TripTreat\\keystore-release.jks')
        storePassword "storePassword"
        keyAlias "keyAlias"
        keyPassword "keyPassword"
    }
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFile getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
}

productFlavors {
    flavor1 {
        proguardFile 'proguard-project.txt'
    }
}

}

dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.0.+'
compile project (":TripTreat:libs:facebook")
compile project (":TripTreat:libs:pull_refresh")
}

dependencies{
compile files ('libs/ksoap2-android-assembly-3.1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar',
        'libs/gson-2.2.4.jar',
        'libs/gson-2.2.4-javadoc.jar',
        'libs/gson-2.2.4-sources.jar',
        'libs/MobileAppTracker-3.2.2.jar')
}
```

I don't know how to use --stacktrace option....

Thank you all!!

EDIT: Studio updated to 1.0 and still happening the same.

Comment: 1.0 stable is out now; does it still happen there? Also, hopefully those aren't your production credentials...

Comment: Yes, I had the 1.0v update after writing the question, but still happen the same...